# How to know which checkboxes were selected in an HTML page through HttpContext.Current.Request.Form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have something like this on my view:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="services-for" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="services-for" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="services-for" />
```

Let's say the user has checked the 1st and 3rd.

My controller function for the POST action looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult SaveProfile()
```

and not `SaveProfile(string name, List<int> servicesFor)` and whatnot due to the extreme number of field inputs (over a 100) and the fact that many of them have values encoded in their names (for example, name="item-542146").

So I am using `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` to access the form values. However, `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["services-for"]` returns null while it works fine for normal text inputs, ie, not multi-selects.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off using a `FormCollection` parameter as follows rather than retrieving values from `HttpContext.Current.Request` as this still allows you to easily test your action methods:

```
public ActionResult SaveProfile(FormCollection form)
{
    var servicesFor = (form["services-for"] ?? "")
        .Split(',')
        .Select(int.Parse);

    // ...
}
```

Note that `form["services-for"]` may return null if there are no checked input items present in the form that was POSTed.

Comment: Thank you; I was not aware of this method and it seems superior. I just tested and form["services-for"] == "1,2,3,4,5", so all is good.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance.  Welcome to StackOverflow!